# How to add a custom view (That extends from View) in Compose block for 1.0.0-beta01

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to include custom view component into Compose section through the function `AndroidView(viewBlock = { customView})`, this works for previous version but now for version **1.0.0-beta01** is not working and i can't find the new way to do that.

This is how the code looks like:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_recipe_lis, container, false)
    view.findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.compose_view).setContent {
        Text("This is a compose view inside a layout")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
        CircularProgressIndicator()
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
        Text(text = "Neat")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))

        val customView = HorizontalDottedProgress(LocalContext.current)
        AndroidView(viewBlock = { customView}) // Error here with the function definition
    }
    return view
}
```

Maybe one of you know. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

you have to pass a factory instead of an instance of the view

```
AndroidView(factory = { HorizontalDottedProgress(it) })
```

or

```
AndroidView(::HorizontalDottedProgress)
```

if you need to configure the view, do it in a trailing lambda

```
AndroidView(::HorizontalDottedProgress) { customView ->
    customView.doSomething()
}
```

read more in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop#views-in-compose)

Answer (score 5):

With `1.0.0-beta02` the [**`AndroidView`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary#androidview) constructor requires a **`factory`** parameter:

> Composes an Android View obtained from `factory`. The `factory` block will be called exactly once to obtain the `View` to be composed, and it is also guaranteed to be invoked on the UI thread.

Example:

```
    //option 1
    val customView = TextView(LocalContext.current).apply { text = "New Text View" }
    AndroidView(factory = { customView })

    //option 2
    AndroidView({ context -> TextView(context).apply { text = "This is a TextView" } })

    //Option 3
    var size by remember { mutableStateOf(100) }
    AndroidView(::TextView,
        Modifier
            .background(Color.Blue)) { view ->
        view.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(size, size)
        view.apply { text = "This is the 3rd TextView" }  }
    }
```

In your case you can just use one of these:

```
    val customView = HorizontalDottedProgress(LocalContext.current)
    AndroidView(factory = { customView }) 

    AndroidView({ context -> HorizontalDottedProgress(context).apply { /* ... */ } })

    AndroidView(::HorizontalDottedProgress) { view ->
        view.apply { /*..*/ }
    }
```